Change VLP-16 laser angle and FOV
I am trying to implement this article: How to Change the Laser Angle and FoV on a Velodyne VLP-16 or this in case the internet archive is down by Frank Bertini.
In my setup, I plan to use only the top-mirror that would reflect some channels and I need to perform transformation on the XYZ data generated from these channels.
Referring to this part from the blog, the reported values from the affected channels should be the mirror image/ reflection, say $P_r = (x_r, y_r, z_r)$ of the actual point, say $P_a = (x_a, y_a, z_a$).

I made this drawing and hope I have done the math correctly. It is side view with X axis to the right and Z upwards,

$O_L$ is the lidar's optical center from where laser is emitted at an angle $\phi$
$O_m$ is the circular mirror's center point right above the lidar's center at a distance $d$
Couple of assumptions that I have made:

Ideally, there should be no roll of the mirror plane wrt to the lidar's XY plane otherwise y co-ordinate will also require transformation.
Yaw doesn't really matter because the mirror is symmetric
A Pitch of angle $\theta$ is considered as shown in the figure.

Lidar's optical center horizontal line is: $z = 0$
Mirror's equation is: $z-d = x \tan(360-\theta) = -x \tan\theta$
In $ax+by+c =0$ form, $x \tan \theta + z - d = 0$
Since VLP's driver already returns us $P_r$ as per the blog, finding $P_a$ is as simple as finding its mirror image/ reflection.
$\frac{x_a - x_r}{\tan\theta} = \frac{z_a-z_r}{1} = \frac{-2(x_r\tan\theta + z_r - d)}{\tan^2\theta + 1^2}$
Solving above gives,
$x_a = x_r + \sin2\theta(x_r\tan\theta + z_r - d)$
$z_a = z_r - 2\cos^2\theta(x_r\tan\theta + z_r - d)$
I want to ask

Is this model even correct?
Does this model miss anything/ any edge case?
If the angle $\phi$ is such that the ray hits near the periphery of the mirror, it should get reflected like that in the image. Will it still be shown in the mirror as a reflection as it is technically out of the FoV of the mirror but the point is still reported by the lidar?
Is there a way to know d from the calculations? I could find it through the documentation CAD drawings though.

